# I need to use sed to comment out two lines in a text file

Tags: regex, bash, sed, comments

I am running a custom kernel build and have created a custom config file in a bash script, now I need to comment out two lines in Kbuild in order to prevent the bc compiler from running. The lines are...

```
$(obj)/$(timeconst-file): kernel/time/timeconst.bc FORCE
    $(call filechk,gentimeconst)
```

Using Expresso, I have a regex that matches the first line...

```
^\$\(obj\)\/\$\(timeconst-file\): kernel\/time\/timeconst\.bc FORCE
```

[Regex Match](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Y4Fi.jpg)

But can't get sed to actually insert a # in front of the line.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following sed for replacement:

```
sed  's,^\($(obj)/$(timeconst-file): kernel/time/timeconst.bc FORCE\),#\1,'
```

You don't need to escape `(` `)` or `$`, as in sed without `-r` it is treated as literal, for grouping `\(` `\)` is used.

Answer (score 1):

`sed -i "/<Something that matches the lines to be replaced>/s/^#*/#/g"`

This uses a regex to select lines you want to comment`/<something>/`, then substitutes `/s/` the start of the string `^`(plus any `#*`s already there, with `#`. So you can comment lines that are already commented no problem. the `/g` means continue after you found your first match, so you can do mass commenting.

I have a bash script that I can mass comment using the above as:

`sed -i.bkp "/$1/s/^#\+\s*//g" $2` 
`i.bkp` makes a backup of the file named .bkp

Script is called `./comment.sh <match> <filename>`

The match does not have to match the entire line, just enough to make it only hit lines you want.

Comment: he's using / in the pattern, so you should use ; or , instead of /.

Comment: Fair point. I use it in my bash scripts and just escape them `\/`, but I also expect to see `;` & `,` regularly.